# How to add Flurry Agent in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I was created one app for windows phone 7 and I want to add flurry analysis for my app, then I implemented start session and end session in App.xaml.cs file.
Now I want to include Flurry Agent for LogError and LogEvent for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?

According to http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/technical-info.html they don't support Windows Phone 7 (yet).

Answer (score 9):

Good news!  We now support WP7.  As you set up a new project in our system, you simply select WP7 as a platform for the right version of the SDK.

Comment: Hi Peter, I've posted a question describing a crash I'm getting with Flurry on Phone 7. Can you have a look here please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161589/flurry-analytics-crashing-with-windows-phone-7