# Flurry WP7 Runs With Debugger Attached/Crashes Without

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, flurry

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7 application and I'm using Flurry to provide analytics for the app.

My problem is simple: When I'm running the app with the debugger attached (either in "Release" or in "Debug" mode), it works fine. When I run it without the debugger attached, it crashes. It doesn't even get to the first screen of the app. It just shows the splash screen and then exits.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161589/flurry-analytics-crashing-with-windows-phone-7 ?

Comment: Looked at it, but I was never getting any kind of "KeyNotFoundException" or first chance exceptions. I cleaned the project to try to clear out the data, but I'm still having the same problems. FWIW, I'm already getting Flurry data from my app for the Debugging sessions I've run, so it is obviously working to some degree.

Comment: Btw. you could consider MessageBox.Show(e.Messsage) in the UnhandledException handler in App.cs.

Answer (score 0):

In this circumstance, depending on the amount of code, I would either try commenting out code back to front using the halving method until you find the place where it is crashing or I would try calling MessageBox.Show going methodically from front to back.

The important thing is to be systematic. I've gotten these kinds of un-debuggable exceptions before and it can be disheartening. You kind of need to shift mindsets from expecting you will know exactly what your code is doing (like an engineer would) to probing and hypothesizing (as a doctor might).